# iPhone Gmail app marks all mail as important

Tags: ios, email, gmail

I'm using the [official Gmail application](https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/gmail/id422689480?mt=8) on my iPhone to receive my Gmail. The reason I use this app is because I label a lot of mails (newsletters for example) so they end up in a folder.

However, all the new e-mail I get also get marked as **Important** and I do not like that.

How can I prevent the Gmail.app from doing this (silly and annoying) behavior?